# How do you increment preface to element using v-for in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am attempting to increment the `i` value in the following code to display search results from an array using Axios for the get request and Vue.js 3:

```html
<div v-if="results" v-for="t in results"> 
    <a :href="'/' + t[i]['1. symbol']">{{ t[i]['1. symbol'] }} -- {{ t[i]['2. name'] }}</a>
</div>
```

Here is a sample API response:

```json
"bestMatches": [
    {
        "1. symbol": "KXI",
        "2. name": "iShares Global Consumer Staples ETF",
        "3. type": "ETF",
        "4. region": "United States",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
        "8. currency": "USD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.8000"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KXIN",
        "2. name": "Kaixin Auto Holdings",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "United States",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
        "8. currency": "USD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.6667"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KXINW",
        "2. name": "Kaixin Auto Holdings - Warrants (30/04/2024)",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "United States",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
        "8. currency": "USD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KXSCF",
        "2. name": "Kinaxis Inc",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "United States",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
        "8. currency": "USD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KX1G.FRK",
        "2. name": "Amundi Index Solutions - Amundi Govt Bond Lowest Rated EuroMTS Investment Grade",
        "3. type": "ETF",
        "4. region": "Frankfurt",
        "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
        "6. marketClose": "20:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
        "8. currency": "EUR",
        "9. matchScore": "0.5000"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KX4A.FRK",
        "2. name": "KLX Energy Services Holdings Inc",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "Frankfurt",
        "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
        "6. marketClose": "20:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
        "8. currency": "EUR",
        "9. matchScore": "0.5000"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KXS.TRT",
        "2. name": "Kinaxis Inc",
        "3. type": "Equity",
        "4. region": "Toronto",
        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
        "8. currency": "CAD",
        "9. matchScore": "0.5000"
    },
    {
        "1. symbol": "KX1G.DEX",
        "2. name": "Amundi Index Solutions - Amundi Govt Bond Lowest Rated Euro Investment Grade UCITS ETF-C",
        "3. type": "ETF",
        "4. region": "XETRA",
        "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
        "6. marketClose": "20:00",
        "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
        "8. currency": "EUR",
        "9. matchScore": "0.4444"
    }
]
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Try this:

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="results" v-for="t in results">
      <a :href="'/' + t[i]['1. symbol']">{{ t[i]['1. symbol'] }} -- {{ t[i]['2. name'] }}</a>
    </div>
    <button @click="incrementI">Next Result</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      i: 
    };
  },
  methods: { incrementI() { this.i++; // Increment the value of i }}
};</script>

Comment: you can pass index variable in for loop like this  

<li v-for="(item, index) in items">
  {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
</li>
documentations link
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for 

I can't format the code and link in the commit if it's not clear to you and you think it's useful I can put it in the answer after a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: You don't

if you want to iterate over an array you can do it like this:

```
<div v-if="results" v-for="t in results"> 
    <a :href="'/' + t['1. symbol']">{{ t['1. symbol'] }} -- {{ t['2. name'] }}</a>
</div>
```

and if you really need the index for something you can do it like this:

```
<div v-if="results" v-for="(t, i) in results"> 
    <a :href="'/' + t['1. symbol']">{{i}}: {{ t['1. symbol'] }} -- {{ t['2. name'] }}</a>
</div>
```

Live example in [Vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: thank you. I have the v-for  however to display the search results I need [i] to increment. I tried i=0; i< this.results.length; i++ in v-for but it didn't work

Comment: @soehlblaze check the second example I gave you, in that example the `i` variable increments on every interaction of the loop. The syntax you provided in the question doesn't make any sense when combined with the example data you provided so I removed it. Do you need two nested loops or what is the problem here? maybe update the question to make it more clear.